# How to know Admin user password in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, password, admin-user

I have many admin users in my magento backend. I want to know one particular user's password, but password stored like below image.
[image]

How to know that user's password **without reset password.**

Is there any way in magento.?

Comment: posting here may help : https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Okay. but i don't know that is it database related or magento related.

Comment: simply, you can't , it is encrypted with md5 , which is not reversible, you can use @mohit kumar arora answer to reset the password ;)

Answer (score 3):

Magento, by default, saves the password in **CONCAT(MD5('qXyourpassword'),':qX')** format, where '**qX**' is **salt value for encryption** and it can be any other string and the string 'yourpassword' can be replaced by the user's password.

If by any chance, the string **qX** is blank, then you can try decoding the password using MD5 decode online tools. But in most cases, it is not possible that the salt value for encryption is empty.

That is why Magento is too secure.

If you want to change the password, you can try the following query:

```
UPDATE `admin_user` SET `password` = CONCAT(MD5('qXpassword'), ':qX') WHERE `username` = 'USERNAME';
```

where 'USERNAME' is the desired username for which you want to reset the password.